# How to overload unary minus operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm implementing vector class and I need to get an opposite of some vector. Is it possible to define this method using operator overloading?

Here's what I mean:

```
Vector2f vector1 = -vector2;
```

Here's what I want this operator to accomplish:

```
Vector2f& oppositeVector(const Vector2f &_vector)
{
 x = -_vector.getX();
 y = -_vector.getY();

 return *this;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Style comment:  don't prefix your variables with '_'.  This style is reserved for the implementation (compiler) and you may have conflicts.  Also, readers my unintentionally recognize your variables as implementation variables because of the '_' prefix.  You don't need to use '_' inside functions; they will be readable without it.

Comment: Two underscores are reserved for implementation, not just one.

Comment: I believe that it's _MACROs and __identifiers.

Comment: Please tell me why you are using `.getX()` and `.getY()` on your simple Vector type

Comment: To be [precise](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers): Identifiers with two subsequent underscores *anywhere* are reserved – *always*, identifiers starting with an underscore followed by a captital letter are *always* reserved, too, any identifier starting with an underscore is reserved *at global namespace*.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Yes, but you don't provide it with a parameter:

```
class Vector {
   ...
   Vector operator-()  {
     // your code here
   }
};
```

Note that you should not return *this. The unary - operator needs to create a brand new Vector value, not change the thing it is applied to, so your code may want to look something like this:

```
class Vector {
   ...
   Vector operator-() const {
      Vector v;
      v.x = -x;
      v.y = -y;
      return v;
   }
};
```

Comment: @Kornel Kisielewicz: Calling it "the *only* right solution" is misleading. Unary `-` can be overloaded by a standalone function as well, which would closely mirror the OP's implementation of `oppositeVector`.

Comment: Should return a const Vector.

Answer (score 35):

It's

```
Vector2f operator-(const Vector2f& in) {
   return Vector2f(-in.x,-in.y);
}
```

Can be within the class, or outside. My sample is in namespace scope.

Comment: +1 for catching that you need to return a new Vector2f instance, not a reference to the current object.

Comment: This is the implementation of a *binary* operator-. Unary has no parameter as @anon said.

Comment: Nope, it is an unary operator. It takes a `Vector2f` as parameter since it is defined in namespace- rather than class scope. My response is correct.

Comment: See also 13.5.1 - 'A prefix unary operator shall be implemented by a non-static member function (9.3) with no parameters or a non-member function with one parameter'.

Comment: @shunz it's an unary operator. note it is namespace scope not class scope.

Comment: Are you citing from Herb Sutter?