# object = -object doesn't compile although operators are overloaded

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overload unary minus operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155275/how-to-overload-unary-minus-operator-in-c)

I have a class C that overloads a number of operators:

```
class C
{
  ...
  C& operator-=(const C& other) {...}
  const C operator-(const C& other) {...}
}
inline const C operator*(const double& lhs, const C& rhs)
```

Now I wanted to invert an object of type C

```
c = -c;
```

And gcc gives me the following error:

```
no match for >>operator-<< in >>-d<<
candidate is: const C C::operator-(const C&)
```

Using c = -1*c works, but I'd like to be able to shorten that. What's missing in my class?

---

Solved: added the unary operator-:

```
C operator-() const {...}
```

as a member of C.

Comment: My situation was slightly different - I didn't know I had to overload the unary operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You overloaded the binary - operator. What you also need is to overload the unary - operator

See

[How to overload unary minus operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155275/how-to-overload-unary-minus-operator-in-c)

for how to overload the unary - operator

Answer (score 3):

You overloaded *binary* `-`, binary `*` and compound assignment `-=` operators. Expression `c = -c` uses *unary* `-`, which you never overloaded.

If you want to overload unary `-` by a standalone (maybe friend) function, you have to declare it accordingly. It can be done inside class definition by simply adding a `friend` keyword

```
class C
{
  ...
  friend C operator-(const C& other) {...}
};
```

or by moving function declaration outside of the class definition

```
class C
{
  ...
};

inline C operator -(const C& other) {...}
```

Alternatively, if you want to declare unary `-` as a member, you have to declare it without parameters

```
class C
{
  ...
  C operator-() const {...}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this change :

```
const C operator-() {...}
```

Comment: Literally just changing the binary operator to unary would have broken quite a lot of my code