# C++ overloading `-` operator (as `* -1`)

Tags: c++, operators

Say I have an `int`, like this:

```
int foo = 5;
```

I could then do this:

```
int bar = -foo;     // -5
```

I want to be able to do the same with my class, so how do I overload the `-` operator, used as `* -1`? Do I have to overload the `*` operator to do so?

Comment: I don't understand what the `-` and the `*` have to do with each other.

Comment: Think of it as `0 - foo`, not `foo * -1`.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Ah, that made me understand what the asker meant.

Comment: Something like the question here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155275/how-to-overload-unary-minus-operator-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class MyClass
{
    friend MyClass operator-(const MyClass& x);
};
```

or

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass operator-() const;
};
```

Take your pick (although I would go for the first).

Comment: Wow, that was simple! I'll accept it once I can verify it works.

Comment: I'd go for the second, unless the `-` operator didn't need access to `protected` or `private` parts of `MyClass`, in which case I'd go for neither and just write `MyClass operator-(const MyClass& x);`. I prefer to avoid `friend` if at all possible.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone A global non-friend function is certainly the best if possible. I put friend there just to emphasize that this option does not involve a member function.

Comment: Why is a global non-friend function or friend function better than a member function? A member function means the declaration is in a place everyone is looking for functionality of the class. It's also logically a function of the class. What benefit is there?

Comment: @Dave There a real problem with member functions for symmetric binary operators (like +, *, < etc) in that the rules of C++ are such that different conversion rules apply to the left and right hand sides of your operator. This isn't a problem for operators which modify an existing object rather than return a new one (like +=). Unary - is somewhere in between, but since it creates a new object rather than modifies an existing one then stylistically I group it with binary +, - etc.