# bigInt addition and subtraction matters

Tags: c++, math, bigint

I am currently doing a school assignment (I am sorry that my question is about my assignment, but I am not asking about the algorithms used in the codes).  I am now currently doing the arithmetic part, addition and subtract.  Since there are only two operators, there are 8 combinations of operation.  In my program, I can do these four cases:

`（+a）+（+b）
（-a）+（-b）
（-a）-（+b）
（+a）-（-b）`

However, I cannot figure out the way to do the other four cases, 
I.e.

`（+a）+（-b）
（-a）+（+b）
（-a）-（-b）
（+a）-（+b）`

I sincerely hope that you guys can provide suggestions and advice on how to deal with these four cases.

Here is my code:

linkedListType.h:
It is a common linked list header file therefore I don't post the whole code here.

bigInteger.h:
The functions in this are quite long.  Therefore, I skipped posting them out.

```
#ifndef BIG_INTEGER_H
#define BIG_INTEGER_H

#include <stack>  
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedListType.h"

using namespace std;

class bigInteger
{
private:
    int sign;                       // set 0 for positive, 1 for negative
    linkedListType<int> digits;     // internal linked-list for storing digits in reverse order

public:
    bigInteger();                           // default constructor
    bigInteger(const bigInteger& other);    // copy constructor

    // Overload constructor
    // Use an numerical string to construct this bigInteger
    // For negative number, the first char in the string is '-'
    // e.g. "-12345"
    bigInteger(const string& number);       

    // overload the assignment operator
    const bigInteger& operator= (const bigInteger& other);

    // Return a new bigInteger that is equal to *this + other
    // The contents of this and other should not be modified
    bigInteger& operator+ (bigInteger& other);

    // Return a new bigInteger that is equal to *this - other
    // The contents of this and other should not be modified
    bigInteger& operator- (bigInteger& other);

    // Print a big integer
    // Since the digits are stored in reverse order in the internal
    // list, you should print in reverse order
    // Print "undefined" if the digits list is empty
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, bigInteger& n);
};
```

Comment: You should add unary operators - e.g. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155275/how-to-overload-unary-minus-operator-in-c).  Note too that it shouldn't be `bigInteger& operator+ (bigInteger& other);` but `bigInteger operator+(const bigInteger& other);` i.e. return *by value* and take the argument by `const` reference.  You may want to write `bigInteger& operator+=(const bigInteger& other);` (and `operator-=`), then you can write `+` as a non-member function like this: `bigInteger operator+(bigInteger lgs, const bigInteger& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }`.

Comment: Similarly, `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, bigInteger& n);` should take `const bigInteger& n`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @TonyD.  But, may i ask some questions?  Would you mind to explain what the use of unary operator is?  Also, what is the function of += and -=?

Comment: I don't understand your question. And it's unlikely the code you've posted is enough for anyone to help you. (Also, "reversely" is not a word.)

Comment: @user2847449: sure - questions welcome.  Say you have `bigInteger x;` and write `-x`, if there's no "left hand side" to subtract `x` from, the compiler will look for a `bigInteger bigInteger::operator-()` function and call that - it should return the negation of `*this` - that's explained at the linked question above.  `+=` and `-=` add and subtract an amount from the value on the left hand side, so `x = x + 3` can be conveniently shortened to `x += 3` if the operators are implemented "normally".  If you're writing `+` and `-` people will kind of expect `+=` and `-=` too.

Comment: After writing unary operators, you can have `（+a）+（+b）` just be resolved as two calls to unary `operator+` followed by one call to the "binary" `operator+`.  Then just write the unary `operator-` and `（-a）+（-b）` will work too, using it and the same binary `operator+`.

Comment: Some basic concepts: 1) expression `a+b` or `a-b`, the + and - are binary operators, called "Addition", and "Subtraction", respectively.  2) expression `(+a)` or `(-a)`, the + and - are unary operators, called "positive", and "negative", respectively.  The symbol for operations may be the same, but the meanings of the operations are different.   So, in fact, you need to overload two kindes of '+' operator, one for "Addition", and the other for "Positive".  The overload function for "Addition" takes one argument, but the one for "Positive" takes no argument.

Comment: @TonyD Thanks for your answer.  However, is it still usable since the numbers are stored in a linked list?  I have googled some codes open in the internet.  Some of them used the method you mentioned but they seems not to be in linked list structure.

Comment: @ooga Thanks for your reply firstly.  Actually, I want to ask whether there is any way to deal with those cases I mentioned that I cannot figure out how to do.  And sorry for the typo "reversely".

Comment: @RobinHsu Thanks for your clarification about the concepts :)

Comment: @user2847449 added an answer to the sign cases ... but without more info on your internal data structure/representation of numbers I can not do more than that ... btw I think this might interest you http://stackoverflow.com/a/26603589/2521214

Comment: "is it still usable since the numbers are stored in a linked list?" - all my comments have been about the proper interface for `bigInteger`... they are still usable... the operator functions should iterate over the linked lists performing the operation.  For example, unary `operator+` should return its argument unchanged, unary `operator-` should return a copy of the argument with the `sign` member toggled, binary `operator+` should probably simplify to either an addition or subtraction of two positive numbers, sometimes negating the result: e.g. `x + y` for -ve x, +ve y = `subtract(y,-x)`.

Comment: Then the private `add` and `subtract` functions can iterate along the lists performing digit-by-digit operations on two known-positive numbers, much like elementary-school maths.

Answer (score 0):

well all the comments are handling the operator overload stuff but I suspect the OP is about how to compute all combinations of signs of operands for addition and substraction.

1. **two's complement**

   well most **HW** implementations of integer **ALU** use two's complement for signed numbers representation. That means:

   ```
   -X = (X^0xFFFFFFFF)+1; // 32 bit example
   ```

   that negative value obtained just by inverting of  all bits and increment the result. So you can use single adder architecture for all add/sub and sign combinations while sign bit is still **MSB**. This encoding handles signed and unsigned operations the same so for addition you have no problem at all (nothing to do just add) and for substraction just invert signum of the second operand and add.

   C++ Implementation looks like this:

   ```
   bool bigInteger::sign() { return MSB_of_this; }
   bigInteger bigInteger::operator+ () { bigInteger z=*this; return z; }
   bigInteger bigInteger::operator- () { bigInteger z=*this; /* here negate all bits and increment z*/ return z' |z; }
   bigInteger bigInteger::operator+ (bigInteger& y)
    {
    bigInteger z;
    // here do z = *this + y as if all operands were positive
    return z;
    }

   bigInteger bigInteger::operator- (bigInteger& y0)
    {
    bigInteger z;
    y=-y0; // invert sign in temp variable to avoid changing input operand value !!!
    // here do z = *this + y as if all operands were positive
    return z;
    }
   ```

   note that I am not changing any input operand and all returns are separate variable (not using this even for unary+). It is due to chain-ability of operands. Some compilers have hard time to daisy chain more then 3 operators in a single line if not coded this way that means you can not compile lines like

   ```
   c=a+b-c*a*b/(s-d)+(23*q);
   ```

   instead you would have to break it down to more simple terms ...
2. **In the case you do not use two's complement**

   Then you have to handle the signs of input operand. The most common case is that you have sign flag as separate variable not inside the number bits. In this case you need some functions that does not take sign into account at all

   ```
   bigInteger uadd(bigInteger &a,bigInteger &b); //=|a|+|b|
   bigInteger usub(bigInteger &a,bigInteger &b); //=|a|-|b| but operands must be: |a|>|b|
   bool        ugeq(bigInteger &a,bigInteger &b); //=|a|>=|b| Unsigned Greater or EQual
   ```

   from this is easy

   **Addition**

   - you can add numbers only if they are the same sign if not the convert it to substraction

   **Substraction**

   - you can sub numbers only if they are the same sign and the first operand is greater or equal then the second one.

   So it would be something like this:

   ```
   bigInteger bigInteger::operator+ (bigInteger& y)
    {
    bigInteger z;
    bool sx,sy;
    sx=sign();
    sy=y.sign();
    if (sx==sy) z=uadd(*this,y);  // same signs is add
    else                            // not then first operand for (a-b) is the positive one
     {
     if (sx) return y-(*this);
     else    return (*this)-y;
     }
    // here set the sign to the same as operands
    z.set_sign(sx);
    return z;
    }
   ```

   as this is an assignment I will leave the `-` operator without code.

   It will be very similar to `+` operator but you need to sort the input operands by absolute size (using `ugeq`) and set the result `sign` from the abs bigger one. if you swapped operands invert the sign of result. Substract only if booth operands are the same sign other wise convert to `(a+b)` ...

Hope it helps a bit

Comment: Just my hunch, but given the question says "internal linked-list for storing digits", I suspect there's a digit per list element, and the bit-wise operations / 2s complement aspects you've documented and would need to know about for an efficiently packed and fast `bigInteger` type aren't needed for this beginner assignment.....

Comment: @TonyD hmm I assumed 2^8+ integer base but yes it is more probable they are just digits. the second half of answer should cover the rest if not it is up to she/him to clarify what is missing to the puzzle...